# Is there a difference between these TimeSpan methods?

Tags: c#

Are these statements syntactically the same and perform the same ?
Which is preferable?

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(100000);
```

or

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(100000);
```

Comment: Yes, they're the same.  But the second version requires implicit knowledge of the default constructor.  I like the first, because it is clear that the timespan is in Ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between them. The static method initialize new instance using the following constructor.

[TimeSpan(Int64)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz841zbz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which initializes a new instance of the TimeSpan structure to the specified number of ticks.

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static TimeSpan FromTicks(long value)
{
    return new TimeSpan(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromticks(v=vs.110).aspx):

> TimeSpan.FromTicks Method (Int64)
>
> This is a convenience method with the same behavior as the `TimeSpan.TimeSpan(Int64)` constructor. A single tick represents
>   one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are
>   10,000 ticks in a millisecond.